# Oracle - two loops in procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need some help in writing Oracle PL/SQL procedure that should do the following:

1. the procedure is called from a trigger after an update of the field in one table with the input parameter B-block or D-activate (this is already done)
2. the procedure should first open one cursor that will catch the account numbers of a client and open a loop that will process account by account
3. this one account should be forwarded to another loop that will catch card numbers of that client for that account (second cursor) and when into this loop, the card number should be used as an input parameter for a stored procedure that is called to block/unblock this card - this stored procedure already exists I just need to call it
4. the procedure don't need to return any parameters, the idea is just to block/activate card number of a client with the already written stored procedure for that

Should I write a package for this or just a procedure? And how can I write one loop in another?

Comment: Just a procedure. Package with a single procedure is *possible*, but - what kind of a "package" is it? A poor one. Though, if you include stored procedure you already have (as described in step #3), that would make 2 of them which makes sense, especially if there'll be another stored procedures/function that deal with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that i can do this without cursors in a procedure. For simple example:

```
create or replace procedure blokiraj_proc (core_cust_id varchar2,  kyc_blocked varchar2) as
type NumberArray is Array(100) of test_racuni.foracid%type;
type StringArray is Array (1000) of test_kartice.card_num%type;

accnt NumberArray;
card_number StringArray;

begin  
    select foracid bulk collect into accnt from test_racuni where cif_id = core_cust_id;

    for i in accnt.first..accnt.last 
    loop
        select card_num  bulk collect into card_number from test_kartice where rbs_acct_num = accnt(i);
        dbms_output.enable (100000);
        dbms_output.put_line (accnt(i));

        for j in 1..card_number.count 
        loop
            dbms_output.put_line (card_number(j));
            blokiraj_karticu (card_number(j));
        end loop;
    end loop;

end;
```

Is this a better approach then the curssors? And why is dbms_output not printing anything when i trigger the procedure?

Comment: Actually, you _are_ using cursors.  Just not explicitly declared cursors.  What do you think the FOR .. LOOP construct is?  dbms_output is no printing anything probably because you didn't 'set serveroutput on'.  BTW, doing this from a trigger sets off red flags in my mind.

Comment: Ok, yes, it was not the right expression, English is not my native language. I meant the explicitly declared cursors. Why doing this from a trigger sets red flag in your mind? The trigger is on another table, when the one field changes then the above decribed should be done. How can I avoid trigger in this case, or what better solution would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

As @EdStevens indicated you cannot avoid processing cursors. But you can avoid the looping structure of cursor within cursor. And the implicit open and close cursor for the inner one. The queries have combine into a simple JOIN then bulk collect into a single collection.  
For this I created a RECORD to contain both the account number and card number; then a collection of that record. The cursor is then bulk collected into the collection. Your initial code allows for up to 100000 cards to be processed, and while I am a fan of bulk collect (when needed) I am not a fan of filling memory, therefore I limit the number of rows bulk collect gathers of each fetch. This unfortunately introduces a loop-within-loop construct, but the penalty is not near as great as cursor-within-cursor construct. The following is the result.

```
 create or replace procedure blokiraj_proc (core_cust_id varchar2) as
    type acct_card_r 
         is record(
            acct_num test_kartice.rbs_acct_num%type
          , card_num test_kartice.card_num%type
          );
    type acct_card_array is table of acct_card_r; 
    acct_card_list acct_card_array; 

    k_acct_card_buffer_limit constant integer := 997;
    cursor c_acct_card(c_cust_id varchar2) is
           select r.foracid 
                , k.card_num
             from test_racuni r
             left join test_kartice k 
                    on (k.rbs_acct_num = r.foracid)
            where r.cif_id = c_cust_id
            order by r.foracid 
                   , k.card_num;
begin 
    dbms_output.enable (buffer_size => null); -- enable dbms_output with size unlimited
    open c_acct_card(core_cust_id); 

    loop 
        fetch c_acct_card
         bulk collect 
         into acct_card_list
        limit k_acct_card_buffer_limit;

        for i in 1 .. acct_card_list.count
        loop
            dbms_output.put (acct_card_list(i).acct_num || ' ==> ');
            if acct_card_list(i).card_num is not null 
            then
                dbms_output.put_line (acct_card_list(i).card_num);
                blokiraj_karticu (acct_card_list(i).card_num);
            else
                dbms_output.put_line ('No card for this account');
            end if; 
        end loop; 

    -- exit buffer fetch when current buffeer is not full. As that means all rows 
    -- from cursor have been fetched/processed.
    exit when acct_card_list.count < k_acct_card_buffer_limit;   
    end loop;

    close c_acct_card;

end blokiraj_proc;
```

Well this is just another approach. If it's better for you, great. I also want to repeat and expand Ed Stevens warning of running this from a trigger. If either of the tables here is the table on which the trigger fired you will still get a mutating table exception - you cannot just hide it behind a procedure. And even if not its a lot of looping for trigger.

Comment: Thank you Belayer, i will try this solution and see how it works. Regarding the trigger, it is on another table after updating one field the above described should be done, I don't see a way to do this without looping.

Comment: Instead of doing that work in a trigger, just do it in the procedure that updates the first table.  See https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/the-trouble-with-triggers